# Pushing a variable's value into an array is returning Void 0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, variables

I'm creating a simple tic-tac-toe game and I'm currently trying to store the user's checks into variables. The problem is, with my current code the xMoves and oMoves arrays are returning Void 0. What's wrong with this code?
http://jsfiddle.net/Z6StP/

```
var storeMoves = function () {
    if (currentPlayer === X) {
        xMoves.push(cellTracker);
    } else if (currentPlayer === O) {
        oMoves.push(cellTracker);
    }
};
```

Comment: The variable of `cellTracker` is undefined in that function.

Comment: @Barmar are you referring to the code in my post or the code in the link?

Comment: They're the same code. The answers explain the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void 0;` is just another way of representing the `undefined` value.

The `.push()` methods are not returning `void 0`. They return the new Array length.

What you're seeing in the console is the Array with `void 0` *(or `undefined`)* inside. That's because you're pushing `cellTracker` into the Arrays, which is never assigned a value.

You *do* have an assignment to `cellTracker`, but that's a local variable. Remove the `var` before it, and you'll be assigning to the outer one.

```
/*var*/ cellTracker = $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: Even better would be to pass `cellTracker` as a parameter to `storeMoves`, instead of using an external variable.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, or perhaps just passing `this.id`.

Comment: Oh boy, I guess I should take this as a sign that I should go to bed...
Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Because you define again the variable `cellTracker` inside the click function of the `td's`.
Remove the definition and use the already defined variable and it will work.

Like:

```
$('td').one('click', function () {
    turnCount += 1;
    setCurrentPlayer();
    $(this).text(currentPlayer);
    cellTracker = $(this).attr('id');
    storeMoves();
    console.log(turnCount, xMoves, oMoves);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Z6StP/1/